# Conceptual difference between seeding and migration

Tags: database-migration, knex.js, seeding

We use knex for database migrations, and we now need to introduce database seeding to the mix. Seeding is a concept in knex, and the seed files are run by separate commands.

Currently, we need to seed the database with certain config values, however, it is not clear to me if this should be done using seeding or migration. I lean towards migration, because the data are unlikely to change, and by using migration, the data will be inserted into the correct schema, regardless of later schema changes and which point in time the seeding is executed. However, it seems a bit unwise to go against such a common pattern as seeding.

My question then, is if there is a practical difference between seeding and migration that I am not aware of, and if it is OK to insert data using the migration process.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a data that should be inserted to DB just once and it should be same in every installation of APP, then migrations is good place to do it.

If data changes between installations, then seeds sounds like something that could be used.

I don't think that seeds should be used with knex for anything else except for maybe inserting some test data for tests to run (even in that case it is usually better to not to use knex's seed feature, but write your own that suits your tests better).

Answer (score 1):

I think Mikael Lepistö makes a great point in their answer.

I feel that it can depend on the data and where you are expecting it to come from.

A good example of data good for migration is static enumerations. These are most likely defined in your code and will not change regardless of environment and is closest to the code that generates it, so migrations make more sense.

A good example for seeding is data generated at run time or from another system. This data could be different based on the environment and integrations, so a seed would better suit.

The idea that seeding is only for test data I do not agree with, but it does lend itself to test data, as this is data dependent on an environment.